# Sequelize create instance of object Many-to-many relationship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, many-to-many

I'm using Sequelize to create an instance of Many-to-Many relationship, but it not working.
First, I have a model with two class as below:

1. Room:

```
    Room.init({
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          primaryKey: true,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
    }, { sequelize, modelName: "Room" }
    );
```

2. User:

```
    User.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          primaryKey: true,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
      },
      { sequelize, modelName: "User"}
    );
```

3. UserRoom:

```
    UserRoom.init("UserRoom", { sequelize });
```

Relationship:

```
    User.belongsToMany(Room, { as:'container', through: UserRoom, foreignKey: "userId" });
    Room.belongsToMany(User, { as:'joiners', through: UserRoom, foreignKey: "roomId" });
```

And the UserRoom has another key with Message Model:

```
    UserRoom.belongsTo(Message, { as: "lastReadMessage" });
```

Ok, now when i create a new Room with code:

```
const room = await Room.create(
  {
    name: name,
    avatarId: avatarUri,
    joiners: [
      {
        id: '1',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    include: [{ association: User, as: 'joiners' }],
  }
);
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I don't know why error, I try [this example](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/) but it still wrong.

My question is: How I create object and link to another relationship?

## UPDATE

---

Now, I can run it with below code:

```
      const room = await Room.create({
        name: name,
        avatarId: avatarUri,
      });
      
      await UserRoom.bulkCreate(
        [
          {
            lastReadMessageId: null,
            userId: 1,
            roomId: room.id,
          },
          {
            lastReadMessageId: null,
            userId: 2,
            roomId: room.id,
          },
        ]
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create users with `id` equals to 1 and 2 along with creating a room. If you wish to associate existing users with a new room then you need to call `addJoiners` of a new room model:

```js
const room = await Room.create(
  {
    name: name,
    avatarId: avatarUri,
);
// pass user instances or ids.
await room.addJoiners([1,2])
```

Comment: I try but it run a query SELECT of UserRoom

Comment: And only SELECT? No INSERTs after that?

Comment: yes, I don't know why

Comment: Does this SELECT returns any records?